# Html parsing in Java using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I've been using Jsoup for HTML parsing, but I encountered a big problem. It takes too long like 1 hour.

Here's the site that I am parsing.

```
<tr>
    <td class="class1">value1 </td>
    <td class="class1">value2</td>
    <td class="class1">value3</td>
    <td class="class1">value4</td>
    <td class="class1">value5 </td>
    <td class="class1">value6</td>
    <td class="class1">value7</td>
    <td class="class1">value8</td>
    <td class="class1">value9</td>
</tr>
```

In the site, there are thousands of tables like this, and I need to parse them all to a list. I only need value1 and value6, so to do that I am using this code.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            ls = new LinkedList();
            for(int i = 15; i<doc.text().length(); i++) {//15 because the tables I want starting from 15
                Element element = doc.getElementsByTag("tr").get(i);//table index
                Elements row = element.getElementsByTag("td");
                value6 = row.get(5).text();//getting value6
                value1 = row.get(0).text();//getting value1
                node = new Node(value1, value6);
                ls.insert(node);
```

As I said it takes too much time, so I need to do it faster. Any ideas how to fix this problem ?

Comment: Parsing a single file takes an hour? How many files are you parsing? How big are they? Are they all present locally before you begin? Or are you crawling a site at the same time?  Seems unlikely that running the code for a single URL would take an hour on modern hardware.

Comment: Can you include anything you have missed, such as the ls, value1, and value 6 variables. Maybe from there I can help out more.

Comment: as I said, there are hundred tables in the site thats all I am parsing, just the tables. No, I am not crawling, and yes its just 1 url consisting tables. The values are just a text, nothing much. For example, value1 is a name like Michael and value6 is just a door number 5.

Comment: and in second code section value6 and value1 is just a String type values.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem stems from the for loop `for(int i = 15; i<doc.text().length(); i++)`. What you do here is loop over the whole text of the document character by character. I highly doubt that this is what you want to do. I think you want to cycle over the table rows instead. So something like this should work:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements trs = doc.select("tr");
for (int i =  15; i < trs.size(); i++){
  Element tr = trs.get(i);
  Elements tds = tr.select("td").;
  String value6 = tds.get(5).text(); //getting value6
  String value1 = tds.get(1).text(); //getting value1
  //do whatever you need to do with the values
}
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. Yes it does what I need, but the speed is the same.

Comment: Can you provide the url you are parsing? How many tables and how many rows are there? Is it maybe so massive, that your computer starts swapping?

Comment: I cant provide the url because of the security reasons. But there are approx. 1400 tables in there.

Comment: Maybe you can split the input html prior parsing into chunks that each can be processed within memory. However, 1400 tables still sounds not like a lot. There may be still something strange in your code. Did you check if maybe the loading of the html (without parsing) already takes so long?